# Handle the onReady event in angular custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an `input` element and, on DOM ready, I attach to this a jQuery plugin:

```
<input id="classic-input" type="text">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#classic-input").tokenInput("http://jquery-tokeninput-demo.herokuapp.com/");
    });
</script>
```

This works pretty well and since I need to use this in various part of my application I've created `template.html` and inserted in it the previous snippet of code, than I created this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', [])
        .directive('myDir', myDir);

    function myDir() {
        return {
            templateUrl : "template.html"
        };
    } 
})();
```

When I insert this directive in the page the form is shown, but nothing happen when I interact with it. I'm pretty sure that `ready` handler is the root of all evil. Am I wrong? If I'm right how can edit this directive?

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FwvxyaXlVGy09wFobLwb?p=preview) is a plunk with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your template is rather small, besides you could skip `script` part - just put your code in directive, like this:

```
function myDir() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element) {
          $(element).tokenInput("http://jquery-tokeninput-demo.herokuapp.com/");
        }
    };
}
```

And apply it to `input` tag like this:

```
<input type="text" my-dir>
```

This way you don't have `id` hard-coded in your template, which will become a problem in case there multiple such directives on page.

See updated [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UQB8CYdPFb8vWlzBYQ42).